# SSIS & SFTP & Putty

Tags: encryption, ssis, sftp, putty

I am designing an integration service to go to an SFTP location, grab an encrypted file, copy it to another server on our network and decrypt the file.  Then use SSIS tasks to load it into a database.

I am using an execute process task to call putty to grab the file, but I'd like to create a new directory on the remote server with the date I'm running the job and move the decrypted file into that directory.

using this commmand with mkdir is creating it on the SFTP server, not the remote server.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir %datestr%
```

I'm new to using putty and encryption so any advice would be welcome.

Essentially I want to do this, but I have to create the date folder in the destination: (I'm not using all 1's for the ip :))

```
get encryptedFile.txt \\111.111.111.111\c$\%datestr%\decryptedFile.txt
```

I'm using this as my starting point - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3435/using-sftp-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: do you mean to create a directory on another server? How do you communicate with 'another' server? if it is ssh, you can connect it with putty and create the expected directory too.

Comment: plink released together with putty could connect to remote server and execute specific command, see [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink)

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear.  Yes, I have a directory for all of the files I download and move, but I'd like to either create a directory with the date on it and then drop the file in, or create a file with the date tagged onto the end, but something I can refer to later.  Essentially, I want to download the encrypted file, decrypt, load into the db, then ditch the decrypted file.